# DatePicker with Decade Calendar to select only year

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

Is there a way to force DatePicker's Calendar to use Decade DisplayMode only, and when year Is clicked on Calendar enter a value of year into DatePicker's Textbox ?

This Is what I have so far:

XAML:

```
   <DatePicker x:Name="Dtp_Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" CalendarOpened="Dtp_Datum_CalendarOpened">
            <DatePicker.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Choose year..."/>
                </Style>
            </DatePicker.Resources>
        </DatePicker>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Dtp_Date_CalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Change drop-down of Calendar to Decade
        DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker)sender;
        Popup popup = (Popup)datepicker.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", datepicker);
        if (popup != null)
        {
            Calendar cal = (Calendar)popup.Child;
            if (cal != null) cal.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Decade;
        }
    }
```

This successfully opens DatePicker's Calendar with DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Decade. But once I click on Calendar It changes DisplayMode to Month (and to Days with another click).

Instead of that I would like Calendar closed and enter a year value in DatePicker's Textbox, nothing else. Is this possible ?

Comment: Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569713/wpf-4-datepicker-how-to-set-displaymode-to-decade) help you?

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski, as I see answer in this thread does same thing for displaying calendar. But it does not involve a part for clicking/closing calendar and updating datepicker's value of selected year. I don't see any Calendar click event, that is why I asked.

Comment: Have you thought about using an editable ComboBox instead? If the goal is to simply select a year, it seems like it would make more sense (for you, and your users) to do it that way.

Comment: @Keithernet,what do you mean by "editable"?... My problem is that users could select whatever year, so I can't just add comboboxitems for all possible years... However If what I asked isn't possible, then I will add Texbox instead - user will enter year and code behind will check If text is really a year (date).... But that is not desired by users...

Comment: What does the year represent? A date birth? A point in history? You don't usually run into situations where a year range is unlimited. Regardless, I think you can emulate some of the behavior and display you want in a really nice way. See my answer below.

Comment: @Keithernet, year represent a parameter for DB procedure, ranges may vary up to 70 years... I don't know why, but users prefer solutions without typing, just a click-to-go. Thanks for suggestion, I will test It.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate some of what you're wanting to do with an editable ComboBox.

The ComboBox is editable which means the user can just type in a year and your can validate it, or they can open the dropdown and see a list similar to how years are displayed in the DatePicker control.

This sample is just bound to a List of years.

```
<ComboBox
    Width="100"
    Height="20"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    IsEditable="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Years}"
    MaxDropDownHeight="168">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel
                MaxWidth="200"
                Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid
                Width="40"
                Height="42">
                <TextBlock
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```